# Create windows script to traverse all subfolders of some folder, and delete a certain folder and all of it's contents if it exists

Tags: powershell, wsh, windows-scripting

here's the trick. Supposing I want to free up some space, and run that script in F:\UnrealProjects, which has a bit over 50-60 subfolders, I would like that script to traverse all of it's subfolders, check whether it contains a folder named `Binaries, Build, Intermediate` and delete everything in it including the folder(s) itself it it exists.

I'm not quite lazy to do it manually once, but when reopening some projects, they do partially or fully rebuild themselves and that eats up space since I really don't need them fully built at all times. I just need to have them archived :) And build only the ones i do want to have built.

Thanks for any help in advance guys (or gals), it's appreciated alot.
If however someone has a better idea to retag this question, I'm all ears and very open to suggestions.

Comment: Nothing really. I've tried deleting them manually, figured out what a chore that will turn out to be, and contemplated whether i should simply write a C program to do that for me, run a bash script thru a VM, or try asking in hopes some good-mannered helpful person throws a script at me and saves me the trouble :) 

I've also asked on SuperUser and the question there does have a nicer "I know it's not very cool just blatantly asking for help/someone to make this script for me, but then again it's just a one-time thing. " line in it.

But if nothing happens i'll try putting a bounty on this one

Comment: Bounty won't help. This is a site for programming questions not a site to post jobs.

Comment: I tried `for /d /r . %%d in (Build,Intermediates,Binaries) do @if exist "%%d" rd /s "%%d"` but that didn't do anything useful. I'm also trying out a few other script forms (involving a for() do { } ) but perhaps someone beats me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, should do it

```
ls -Recurse -Include Build,Intermediates,Binaries -Attribute Directory | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: giving it a try right now :) EDIT: can i somehow echo the things it wants to delete first, just to double-check it doesn't delete more than it should?

Comment: sorry, no. it says `ls: unknown option --e`. When i changed ls to dir, it jjust gave me `U:\Unreal Projects` seven times with a `File Not Found` at the end. :(

Comment: You can try running the command without the remove-item part or you can add -Confirm and it will prompt you to confirm whether you want to delete or not

Comment: try gci instead of ls
are you using powershell?

You should running it from u:\unreal projects

Comment: it seems I am not, i'm merely using command prompt. sorry for my lack of knowledge and ignorance on this topic :( 

but i'm in plain command prompt, trying to find out a batch-file solution, or some other windows-scripting solution without even really knowing what "windows scripting" is. On linux, it's bash. On windows, i just naively presumed it was called powershell when it's in fact just cmd.exe

Comment: you can start powershell from the command prompt, just type powershell

Comment: aha, now i'm getting somewhere :)
When I ommited the `| Remove-Item -Force -Recurse` part, it threw an error at me, saying that `Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches paremeter name 'Attribute'.`
However, when I deleted the attribute and just left it as `ls -Recurse -Include Build, Binaries, Intermediate, Saved` it listed all folders where it found one or more of those included folders :)

Comment: So, I guess if I add the `| Remove-Item -Force -Recurse' part, powershell will just delete them? And how would I best transfer all of this to a clickable .bat file, just write `powershell` at the start followed by the command you posted? :) So far it's working much better than i expected.

Comment: Before I accept this, I have one more question please - certain projects require plugins, which usually have a Binaries folder of their own. How would I avoid deleting the `Project\Plugins\Binaries` folder that appears for some projects?